# LULU Smoother, how is L and U combined?

Tags: signal-processing

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lulu_smoothing

I'm interested in using this approach to remove signal spikes from an analog sensor connected to a microcontroller. I understand the L and U operations, however the Wikipedia page fails to indicate how these two results would be combined.

Is the resulting dataset from L fed into U (or vise versa for UL). IE L(U(dataset))?

Comment: Going by the figures in Wikipedia's "Examples" section, LU means apply L then U, i.e. U(L(data)). However according to Conradie et al. (2006) it means the opposite. I didn't check the other references.

Comment: The article states "*The Lulu smoothers are composed of repeated applications of the L (lower) and U (Upper) operators*". I guess it is up to the user to decide on the order and number of successive applications of L and U.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rohwer's original paper, "[Idempotent one-sided approximation of median smoothers](https://dx.doi.org/10.1016%2F0021-9045%2889%2990017-8)" (1989), appears to be available online as open access. It applies operators on the left, so $L_nU_nx$ means apply $U_n$ to the sequence $x$ and then apply $L_n$ to the result.

(The figures on Wikipedia are inconsistent with Rohwer's notation.)